# The outlook app doesn't have the function getItemIdAsync but the web outlook has when creating an web addin for appointments

Tags: outlook, outlook-web-addins

I am developing an outlook web addin for appointments.
To see if the appointment was a new one or it was one already created I was using the function Office.context.mailbox.item.getItemIdAsync, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.appointmentcompose?view=outlook-js-preview#getitemidasync-options--callback-, if I received an id it was a created one if not it was a new one, this in the outlook web works perfectly in the outlook app no.
I need this id to make EWS requests.

when I was debugging on the outlook app I discovered that this function doesn't exist

[all functions in the outlook app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7EiH.png)

and when I run it I get this error:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEeyK.png)

My questions are:

- should this happen?
- I need something else?
- is there any other way to get the id?

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: To use getItemIdAsync you need at a minimum API requirement set Mailbox 1.8. You can check if it's supported using [Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/outlook-api-requirement-sets#using-apis-from-later-requirement-sets). And make sure that your [Outlook client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/outlook-api-requirement-sets#outlook-client-support) also supports 1.8.

Comment: that was the problem thank you

Comment: just noting that I am moving comment to answer

Answer (score 0):

To use getItemIdAsync you need at a minimum API requirement set Mailbox 1.8. You can check if it's supported using Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported. And make sure that your Outlook client also supports 1.8.